# Custom paper size not being applied for Access report

Tags: windows-7, printing, microsoft-access-2007

I have a Microsoft Access 2007 report that uses a custom paper size so I can print to a label printer.

When I run this report on another workstation, it chooses an incompatible paper size and prints across 4 or more labels.

The other computer has the same operating system (Win 7 64-bit), same print driver version, and same printer.....physically the same printer. The correct printer "form" is installed on each workstation, and it's chosen as the default form.  The correct size is listed among the options when you select the printer and click the "print server properties" in the control panel.  At print time, however, the driver has the wrong paper size selected.

The only difference is my computer has Access 2007 installed and the other workstation has the 2007 Runtime.

What could explain this behavior?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by the correct printer form being installed.  Is the correct paper size selected in the printer driver at print time (could be separate from a form definition that Access uses)?

Comment: By form, I mean the correct size is listed among the options when you select the printer and click "print server properties" in control panel

Comment: At Print time, the driver has the wrong paper size selected